# C/C++: How to figure out the chain of header files for a given definition?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, header

In Visual C++, one can find the header file where any **name** (variable or type) is **defined** by pressing F12 on it or choosing **Go to Definition**. This feature is very useful, but it only shows the **final location** (header file) where the name is defined. Is there a way to figure out the **chain** of header files that lead from my source file to the final header file for a given name?

For example, consider this code:

```
// main.cpp    
#include <stddef.h>
int main()
{
    size_t s;
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual C++ 2010, if I look up the definition of `size_t` in the above `main.cpp`, it lands me in some file named `sourceannotations.h`. I know that this header chain begins with `stddef.h` (which I have included) and ends in `sourceannotations.h`. How to figure out the links in the middle of this chain?

Comment: If you're looking for a hotkey in Visual Studio(tm) or for a Visual Studio(tm) Certified(r) plugin to do this, you probably should tag your question with one of Visual Studio(tm)-related tags...

Comment: Pavel: I was not looking for such a hotkey. But, will tag it with VS anyway since such a solution will be useful too :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Right click project, "Project Properties"
2. "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Advanced".
3. Set "Show Includes" to "Yes".

The complete hierarchy of headers will be printed out in the output window when you compile every file.

Comment: This works! It does not show the chain for a certain name, but almost suits my need. Thanks! :-)

Comment: For the curious, the header chain for size_t in VC++ 2010 turned out to be: stddef.h -> crtdefs.h -> sal.h -> sourceannotations.h

Comment: @Ashwin: you won't get an exact chain of dependencies, because the header may be included from multiple places. What's worse, C++ allows duplicate typedefs to the same type. Now you have a tree, instead of a chain.

Comment: Alex: Yes, I realize that for any real-world example the inclusion might have occurred from anywhere. But, this is still a useful tool to investigate the header chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse engineering tools like Doxygen, Understand Analyst etc. This will help you understand the full flow of variables, function calls.

Comment: +1 for referring to Understand for C/C++, but this still requires you to open the include chart in Understand and click-open every include until you found the include file where the variable/type/constant is actually defined.  So, still lots of manual work.  But, on the other hand, indeed very good utility.

Answer (score 1):

In your properties dialog, under C/C++, Preprocessor, enable Preprocess to a File.  If you compile main.cpp, this will generate main.i.

You can then look in main.i and see which file includes what other file.

Comment: That was also my initial idea (using the /P compiler option), but from that generated .i file I think it is still difficult to see what the actual 'chain' is.