# How can I find the chain of includes that leads to a declaration using Linux tools?

Tags: c++, c, kdevelop

As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177584), I'd like to find the chain of `#include`s by which a particular definition winds up being incorporated into my C/C++ file. For example, suppose `main.c` contains this code

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    double d = exp(0);
    return 0;
}
```

then on my system (fairly standard Linux), `math.h` includes `bits/mathcalls.h` which is where `exp()` is declared. So I would like to run some sort of analysis on `main.c` and get output like

```
exp:
 main.c
 math.h
 bits/mathcalls.h
```

The formatting is irrelevant, I just want the complete chain of included files from where `exp()` is used to where it is declared. Is there some Linux-compatible tool which I can use to do this?

The question I linked above gives a way to do it in Visual Studio, but that doesn't work for me for obvious reasons. I do use Kdevelop, so if I can do it in that program, that will be fine, or some command line tool would be good as well.

Comment: Of the top of my head: You and a gazillion other c and c++ developers. Dependency resolving is a complex issue in this realm.

Comment: Have you considered [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/)? I can personally recommend it; [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAMREnzoReader.html) has a public example you can browse through to see if it's what you're looking for (file kind of chosen at random, but does a nice job of displaying the power of Doxygen).

Comment: @MrDuk I didn't know Doxygen could do that. If you could point me to some instructions to get me started that would constitute a very acceptable answer.

Comment: Try gcc -E, this resolves all your #includes and prints out the code. It is nearly impossible to read, but in combination with less and a good search functionality, you only use quite native tools.

Comment: @EGOrecords I had considered that, but as you say it's exceedingly difficult to follow. If you have some recommendations as to how to extract a chain of included files from the preprocessor output, or some other way to reduce the complexity to a manageable level, that would be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do this, either natively or with minimal changes to the configuration file.

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/annotated.html) has a nice public page that you can browse around in - specifically though, if you have a look at one of their high-level domains: [vtkObjectBase](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/annotated.html) you can start to see the depth of information Doxygen gives.

If you have a look at [vtkObject](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkObject.html), you immediately see all of the modules which inherit this class. Additionally, you can click on the [Class Members](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/functions.html) link and see specifically which modules inherit which members (e.g., [Observer](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/functions_o.html#index_o) belongs to vtkDataRepresentation , vtkOrientationMarkerWidget , vtkPainter , vtkPainterPolyDataMapper , vtkTextRepresentation).

Lastly, here's a [Doxygen setup tutorial](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html) (though there may be additional 1-2-3 step outlines somewhere on the web).

Comment: The key information I'd be looking for are the configuration file properties that would need to be set. I think I managed to figure them out, but the resulting include dependency graphs only go one level beyond the files in my project, which is not far enough for my purposes.